# Ansible errros out when daemon_reload=yes with error failure 1 during daemon-reload: Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out

Tags: ansible

My YAML file for the handler is as below: Yaml file location is as below

**ansible_patching/ssm_agent.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true

  roles:
  - ssm_agent
```

**roles/ssm_agent/handlers/main.yml**

```
# handlers file for ansible-role-ssm-agent
- name: systemctl_handler
  systemd:
    name: amazon-ssm-agent
    daemon_reload: yes
    state: "{{ ssm_agent_svc_state }}"
    enabled: yes
```

**ansible_patching/roles/ssm_agent/tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Check required input parameters
  assert:
    that:
      - ({{ item }} is defined)
      - ({{ item }} is not none)
      - ({{ item }} | trim != '')
  with_items:
    - os_name
    - os_version
  loop_control:
          loop_var: item
- name: Include architecture specific
  include: "{{ ansible_architecture }}.yml"

- name: Include for centos 7
  include: install_{{ os_name }}_{{ os_version }}.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == "{{ os_name }}" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "{{ os_version }}"
```

The error I get is as below

```
RUNNING HANDLER [ansible_role_ssm_agent : systemctl_handler] ********************************************************
fatal: [13.236.87.146]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "failure 1 during daemon-reload: Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out\n"}
```

However, I can restart service with the same remote user(ansible) on the remote host [ Public IP of Remote CentOS Host ]

Please find below output:

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-33-3 tmp]$ sudo systemctl status amazon-ssm-agent
[sudo] password for ansible:
● amazon-ssm-agent.service - amazon-ssm-agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/amazon-ssm-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-25 01:22:40 UTC; 44min ago
 Main PID: 1978 (amazon-ssm-agen)
   CGroup: /system.slice/amazon-ssm-agent.service
           └─1978 /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent

[ansible@ip-172-31-33-3 tmp]$ sudo systemctl restart amazon-ssm-agent
[ansible@ip-172-31-33-3 tmp]$ sudo systemctl status amazon-ssm-agent
● amazon-ssm-agent.service - amazon-ssm-agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/amazon-ssm-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-06-25 02:07:06 UTC; 2s ago
 Main PID: 2157 (amazon-ssm-agen)
   CGroup: /system.slice/amazon-ssm-agent.service
           └─2157 /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent
```

**Note:** The playbook (ansible ssm agent installation role) does work fine if I **comment** **daemon_reload: yes**

Any guidance shall be appreciated.

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-38-88 ~]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[ansible@ip-172-31-38-88 ~]$ echo $?
0
```

Edit 2: Works fine on the remote host with sudo command

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-38-88 ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers |grep ansible
[sudo] password for ansible:
ansible ALL=(ALL)       ALL
[ansible@ip-172-31-38-88 ~]$
```

Edit 4: Remote ansible user has identical permissions like root user.

Comment: Do you need the `daemon-reload` attribute? This should execute `systemctl daemon-reload` on the remote machine. Can you successful execute it as the ansible user?

Comment: The manual thing did not work Sir. I pasted the output after P.S. I don't know if I need that attribute. I added as a precautionary measure.

Comment: Sorry. You need to issue the command with `sudo`. Is this possible? `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: You need sudo permissions - add `become: true` in the `systemd` section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the details in your question, I can see that you are using `ansible` user to log in the remote machines.

In order to start-stop-restart or reload the system services, your `ansible` user has to have administrative rights, meaning the `sudo` rights.

From the output of `systemctl daemon-reload` we can clearly see that you don't have required permissions. So, in order to make it work,

1. You need to give sudo rights to your `ansible` user,

   In Ubuntu, (with root user or sudo):

   ```bash
   usermod -aG sudo ansible
   ```

   In CentOS (with root user or sudo):

   ```bash
   usermod -aG wheel ansible
   ```
2. You need to set `become: true` in your playbook,

   ```yaml
   ---
   - name: My playbook
     hosts: localhost
     become: true
     become_user: root
     become_method: sudo

     tasks:
   ```

and that's all!

Comment: can you please share your playbook in the question as well?

Comment: Sir, I have updated the playbook with all YAML files plus remote ansible user permissions, kindly assist.